# How to iterate to Profile pictures in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

User stored his/her profile picture in "Shared%20Pictures/Profile%20Pictures/bhind8ball.bmp" path in SSP.

How to get this List item using this url? Or How to iterate SharePicture/ProfilePicture to get this List item using SPQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to parse the picture url or are you trying to just simply access their profile picture?

**Edit**
If you are simply trying to access their profile picture you can access this through the object model of the users profile, the property name is PictureURL. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms492435(office.12).aspx